# How would I enable the NEXT button only when any one of the radiobutton + any one of the listbox item are selected?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form programmed using C#. I am using .Net 4.0. In the form, I have two radiobuttons and a listbox of 4 items and a button named "NEXT"

I would like NEXT button enabled only when any one of the radiobutton + any one of the listbox item are selected. I searched through this site and couldn't find anyone doing the same thing as me.

Comment: are you using mvvm? if so share your ListBox ItemTemplate and the ViewModel

Comment: Welcome!  Post your XAML

Answer (score 0):

Have the checked property within your `XAML` for your `RadioButton`:

```
<RadioButton Content=""
         Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
         />
```

Then within your code behind which is the event handler of the `Checked` event try inserting the code for to enable the `Button`.

private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Enable the button here, i assume your button name is Name:newB
        newB.IsEnabled = True
    }

Then in order to do something when an item from the `Listbox` is selected, have the `SelectionChanged` property within your `ListBox` element in xaml:

```
ListBox SelectionChanged="OuterListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="outerListBox">
```

Then in the code behind of the event handler:

```
 private void OuterListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         newB.IsEnabled = True
    }
```

Reference: [isEnabled property](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isenabled)

Comment: According to your code, the Button will be enabled whenever any RadioButton is checked or a ListBox item is selected. But the question is need to check whether both are done, if so only yje button should be enabled. It should check for both the conditions.

Comment: Then insert a condition in either one of those event handler, checking whether the other one is done and then enable the button. If not make the `IsEnabled` as false.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can have two flags (RadioChecked and ListItemSelected). And have a method SetEnable() in which check both of these flags. If both are True, then set isEnable to True. Else set as False. And at the RadioButton Checked event, set the RadioChecked button to True and call the SetEnable. Also at the SelectionChanged event of ListBox you can do the same.

```
    bool IsRadioChecked = false;
    bool IsItemSelected = false;
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsRadioChecked = true;
        SetEnable();
    }

    private void ListBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            IsItemSelected = true;
        if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            IsItemSelected = false;
        SetEnable();
    }
    public void SetEnable()
    {
        if (IsRadioChecked && IsItemSelected)
            btn.IsEnabled = true;
        else
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

And if you are using MVVM, you may need to have 3 bool properties in MVVM
as follows

Bind this property to IsChecked property of both the RadioButton. So that, if any one is checked means, it will be true.
        private bool isRadioButtonChecked;

```
    public bool IsRadioButtonChecked
    {
        get { return isRadioButtonChecked; }
        set { 

            isRadioButtonChecked = value;
            if (IsItemSelected && isRadioButtonChecked)
                BtnEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

set this property to True, if any of the item in listBox is selected. 
        private bool isItemSelected;

```
    public bool IsItemSelected
    {
        get { return isItemSelected; }
        set { isItemSelected = value; }
    }


    Bind the BtnEnabled property to IsEnabled property of Button.
    private bool btnEnabled;

    public bool BtnEnabled
    {
        get { return btnEnabled; }
        set { btnEnabled = value; }
    }
```

And a selectedItem property which should be bind the SelectedItem of ListBox.

```
       private object selectedItem;
       public object SelectedItem
        {
         get { return selectedItem; }
         set 
         { 
            selectedItem = value; 
            if(SelectedItem!= null)
            {
                IsItemSelected = true;
                if (IsRadioButtonChecked)
                    BtnEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this would helps you.